# WPF strange exception in system thread

Tags: c#, wpf, exception

I have WPF application with some 3D Rotator based on Viewport2DVisual3D.

Sometimes on some production PCs program throws exception in system thread.
Exceptions generated very often - 10-20 ms one by one. At this moment UI thread not responding, CPU eat 25% of quad cores - so 1 core full loaded, but OS not generate "Not responding" for application.

Stacktrace

> System.InvalidCastException: Unable to cast object of type
>   'System.Windows.Media.Media3D.Viewport2DVisual3D' to type
>   'System.Windows.Media.Visual'.
>       at System.Windows.Documents.AdornerLayer.GetClipGeometry(Visual element, Adorner adorner)
>       at System.Windows.Documents.AdornerLayer.UpdateElementAdorners(UIElement
>   element)
>       at System.Windows.Documents.AdornerLayer.UpdateAdorner(UIElement element)
>       at System.Windows.Documents.AdornerLayer.OnLayoutUpdated(Object sender, EventArgs args)
>       at System.Windows.ContextLayoutManager.fireLayoutUpdateEvent()
>       at System.Windows.ContextLayoutManager.UpdateLayout()
>       at System.Windows.ContextLayoutManager.UpdateLayoutCallback(Object arg)
>       at System.Windows.Media.MediaContext.InvokeOnRenderCallback.DoWork()
>       at System.Windows.Media.MediaContext.FireInvokeOnRenderCallbacks()
>       at System.Windows.Media.MediaContext.RenderMessageHandlerCore(Object
>   resizedCompositionTarget)
>       at System.Windows.Media.MediaContext.RenderMessageHandler(Object resizedCompositionTarget)
>       at System.Windows.Threading.ExceptionWrapper.InternalRealCall(Delegate
>   callback, Object args, Int32 numArgs)
>       at MS.Internal.Threading.ExceptionFilterHelper.TryCatchWhen(Object source, Delegate method, Object args, Int32 numArgs, Delegate
>   catchHandler)

Any idea where maybe problem and how find this place? On development PC's this problem not reproduced and on production not on all and not stable.

Thanks.

Update.

Viewport2DVisual3D used only in xaml as control and in c# back code for animation like this

> Storyboard.SetTarget(page3DYShowAnimation, page.GetV2DV3D());
>   Storyboard.SetTargetProperty(page3DYShowAnimation, new
>   PropertyPath("(Viewport2DVisual3D.Transform).(Transform3DGroup.Children)[1].(RotateTransform3D.Rotation)"));
>
> ScaleTransform trans = new ScaleTransform();
>   page.GetRot3D().RenderTransformOrigin = new Point(0.5, 0.5);
>   page.GetRot3D().RenderTransform = trans; DoubleAnimation anim = new
>   DoubleAnimation(0.85, 1, TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(500));
>   trans.BeginAnimation(ScaleTransform.ScaleXProperty, anim);
>   trans.BeginAnimation(ScaleTransform.ScaleYProperty, anim);
>
> var storyboard = new Storyboard(); var pTimeline = new
>   ParallelTimeline(); pTimeline.Children.Add(page3DYShowAnimation);
>   pTimeline.Children.Add(pageSlideHideAnimation);
>   storyboard.Children.Add(pTimeline); storyboard.Completed +=
>   storyboard_Completed;
>
> storyboard.Begin(page.GetCont3D(), true);

In storyboard_Completed some another animations.

Comment: Can you post some relevant code?

Comment: It's a main problem which code is relevant. Application have many pages and visually navigation to next page and back realized over rotate this page in 3D. But exception occurs when destination page already on place and user make some operations like scroll part of content (but it's not important to scroll).

Comment: the method `GetClipGeometry` gets a `System.Windows.Media.Media3D.Viewport2DVisual3D` based instead of an `System.Windows.Media.Visual` based object. search in your program for the method `GetClipGeometry` and figure out who gives the wrong element to this method

Comment: Well...this is just a stack trace, it's virtually impossible to suggest anything else than "look for places where a Viewport2DVisual3D gets cast to a Visual". Given that it's not a reliably reproducible crash, most likely there is some updating of the visual tree from another thread going on, but it's impossible to tell.

Comment: In my code I never cast Viewport2DVisual3D. And never execute GetClipGeometry. This is not my thread - it's some system thread I think. I'll update question with some my code sample